# Como criar comandos para disparos através de uma tarefa CRON

Tags: php, cron

Não tenho acesso ao CPanel Linux e foi solicitado para enviar o script de comando para a pessoa responsável. Não tenho também muito conhecimento em tarefas cron e gostaria de saber como posso criar uma para que seja enviado diariamente um disparo de cobrança para os usuários. Pensei em usar dessa forma, mas nao sei se está correta:

```
0   0   *   *   *   
curl -s -o /dev/null http://site.com.br/disparar-cobranca/index.php
```

Poderiam me ajudar para que eu possa enviar o comando correto? O servidor é da Locaweb e a versão do PHP é 5.2.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O título da pergunta não sugere o mesmo que o conteúdo da pergunta.

Na minha interpretação você precisa "testar" seu *script* para saber se é funcional. Então vamos lá!

Sim, o script é **FUNCIONAL**. Mas tem uma pequena questão[zinha].

Quando você chama o `curl` com parâmetro `-s`, ele não gera saída.

Quando você chama o `curl` com parâmetro `-o`, ele armazena a saída em tal arquivo.

Então, para corrigir seu *script* (a pesar de ser funcional), apenas chame o `curl` com o parâmetro `-s` e o caminho da requisição:

```
curl -s http://site.com.br/disparar-cobranca/index.php
```

Outra coisa: Se você está solicitando isso de uma empresa, obviamente ela tem acesso ao *shell* do servidor. Então, seria mais adequado chamar o seu *script* direto com o *PHP*. Bastaria saber o caminho do *PHP* no servidor, que acabaria ficando por conta de quem vai instalar seu *cronjob*. Normalmente fica em `/usr/local/bin/php`. Daí sua *cronjob* ficaria assim:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /caminho/do/site/no/servidor/index.php
```

PS: `/caminho/do/site/no/servidor/index.php` deve ser alterado conforme o caminho do seu site, como já ficou explícito. Normalmente fica em `/var/www/html`.

Se o objetivo do seu *cronjob* é rodar esse *script PHP* **todos os dias às 0h (meia-noite)**, vai funcionar certinho.

Comment: Olá @LipESprY. Perfeito. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.